# Writing a schema for my simple tree like xml data

Tags: xsd

Please let me know how to write a schema for my simple xml data.
It is like the following example. Where both of the 2 attributes are of integer type,
or of the most efficient data type.

```
<node id="1" parent="">
 <node id="2" parent="1">
  <node id="3" parent="2"></node>
  <node id="4" parent="2"></node>
 </node>
</node>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what kind of tools do you have available? What platform are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just generated this by dropping your sample XML onto http://www.flame-ware.com/products/xml-2-xsd/default.aspx

It looks pretty useful as a starting point?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Generated using Flame-Ware Solutions XML-2-XSD v2.0 at http://www.flame-ware.com/Products/XML-2-XSD/ -->
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="node">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="node" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:attribute name="parent" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="node" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```